# Errors installing Netfaces for Python in Win10

Tags: python, c++, windows, octoprint

I am trying to set up an Octoprint server on an old but perfectly servicable Win10 Laptop workstation, however, during the final octoprint install, I get this error (see attached image) noting that I require a later version of C++, at least ver 14 or later, however, I have ver 16 installed, and so the error makes no sense... to me

Am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBKz1.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue just fine... only thing is, now I can't find Localhost!